# Is there any way to remove own device policy controller

Tags: android, locked

My Device is locked with own device policy controller it's a credit device

I tried to disabled it but the option is closed and uninstall option is also closed even forced stop is not working l have even tried to used uninstall application that App is not uninstalled

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.